# Is it a critical bug in PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a master drive holding various files, those files are shared with different users using different permissions. The problem that I'm having can be reproduced following these steps:

On master drive:

- Insert a new file named **testFile** with MimeType of application/vnd.google-apps.document
- Insert a **'write'** permission for **user1**
- Insert a **'read'** permission for **user2**

On user2 drive:

- Create a new folder **'Test folder'**
- Use Patch command to assign a new parent folder of **'Test folder'** for the
  shared file **testFile**

What will happen is **user2** will have a **NEW permission** of **'write'**, user2 can start editing the shared file.

Anyone has any solution to this issue?

EDIT: this is the test that fails

```
public class UserOverridesPermissionTest
{
    private string m_masterEmail;
    private string m_userEmail;

    private DriveService m_masterDrive;
    private DriveService m_userDrive;

    public UserOverridesPermissionTest(string masterDriveEmail, string userDriveEmail, GoogleDriveConfig config)
    {
        m_masterEmail = masterDriveEmail;
        m_userEmail = userDriveEmail;

        var cert = new X509Certificate2(config.PrivateKeyPath, config.KeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        m_masterDrive = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(config.ServiceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                User = m_masterEmail
            }.FromCertificate(cert))
        });

        m_userDrive = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(config.ServiceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                User = m_userEmail
            }.FromCertificate(cert))
        });
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var testFile = m_masterDrive.Files.Insert(new File()
        {
            Title = "testFile",
            MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
        }).Execute();

        m_masterDrive.Permissions.Insert(new Permission()
        {
            Value = m_userEmail,
            Role = "reader",
            Type = "user"
        }, testFile.Id).Execute();

        var testFolder = m_userDrive.Files.Insert(new File()
        {
            Title = "test folder",
            MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        }).Execute();

        m_userDrive.Files.Patch(new File()
        {
            Parents = new []
            {
                new ParentReference()
                {
                    Id = testFolder.Id
                }
            }
        }, testFile.Id).Execute();

        var permissions = m_masterDrive.Permissions.List(testFile.Id).Execute();
        Assert.AreEqual("reader", permissions.Items.Single(p => p.EmailAddress == m_userEmail).Role);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you make "test folder" the parent of "testFile", what user are you doing that as?

Comment: I'm using user2's account

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.  You could provide sample code, or a series of steps in the api explorer that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thank you, we are investigating.